# Add element in the array of hash object

Tags: ruby

To a hash of arrays of hashes like

```
{'1' => [{'a' => 'ss', 'b' => 'tt'},
         {'a' => 'sdd', 'b' => 'tdd'}],
 '2' => [{'a' => 'ffff', 'b' => 'sds'}],
 '3' => [{'a' => 'ddd', 'b' => 'ssss'},
         {'a' => 'sss', 'b' => 'sssss'}]}
```

I want to add `'c' => 'xyz'` in every hash in the arrays to get

```
{'1' => [{'a' => 'ss', 'b' => 'tt', 'c' => 'xyz'},
         {'a' => 'sdd', 'b' => 'tdd', 'c' => 'xyz'}],
 '2' => [{'a' => 'ffff', 'b' => 'sds', 'c' => 'xyz'}],
 '3' => [{'a' => 'ddd', 'b' => 'ssss', 'c' => 'xyz'},
         {'a' => 'sss', 'b' => 'sssss', 'c' => 'xyz'}]}
```

How I can I implement this?

Comment: Have you tried anything, yet?

Answer (score 1):

```
my_arrays = {'1' => [{'a' => 'ss', 'b' => 'tt'},
                     {'a' => 'sdd', 'b' => 'tdd'}],
             '2' => [{'a' => 'ffff', 'b' => 'sds'}],
             '3' => [{'a' => 'ddd', 'b' => 'ssss'},
                     {'a' => 'sss', 'b' => 'sssss'}]}

my_arrays.each do |key, value|
  value.each do |val|
    val.store('c', 'xyz')
  end
end
```

Comment: can we achieve this by iterating once  instead of 2 each loops ?

Comment: i am a newbie of ruby, so i really don't know, if it is possible or not. but your hash seems having 2 different data type, hash and array - and they are nested. iterating over hashes is first thing to do - to grab the array, then another iteration needed to grab the hash inside the array.

for iterating over hash you need key and value, for array just value is sufficient. there is a structural difference between methods - so, it seems impoossible to me now. but let me rewrite again, i'm a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

```
h = {'1' => [{'a' => 'ss', 'b' => 'tt'},
             {'a' => 'sdd', 'b' => 'tdd'}],
     '2' => [{'a' => 'ffff', 'b' => 'sds'}],
     '3' => [{'a' => 'ddd', 'b' => 'ssss'},
             {'a' => 'sss', 'b' => 'sssss'}]}

h.values.each do |ary|
  ary.each do |inner_hash|
    inner_hash['c'] = 'xyz'
  end
end
```

Above solution is very similar to [marmeladze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29582161/674064), so let me just explain the differences:

- We don't need to do anything with the keys of the outer hash. So we can directly use the outer hash's values for iteration and not care about the keys at all.
- `inner_hash['c'] = 'xyz'` uses element assigment syntax instead of calling [`#store`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Hash.html#method-i-store). They do [exactly the same](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D).

In a comment to marmeladze's answer, you asked:

> can we achieve this by iterating once instead of 2 each loops ?

`h.values` gives us an array of arrays. (Because it gives the array of values of `h` and the values of `h` are arrays.) We can collapse nested arrays with `flatten` and thus can achieve the same result with only one explicit iteration:

```
h.values.flatten.each do |inner_hash|
  inner_hash['c'] = 'xyz'
end
```

or, (equivalently) if you prefer it all on one line

```
h.values.flatten.each { |ih| ih['c'] = 'xyz' }
```